# Hibernate doesn't want to map the class in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have a class User which is Entity. When I'm trying to map it in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping class="com.igorgorbunov3333.entities.User"/>
```

get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown
> entity: com.igorgorbunov3333.entities.User

But when I map class User programmatically It's work fine.

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
```

What is the reason?

My Entity class:

```
package com.igorgorbunov3333.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * Created by Игорь on 01.07.2016.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: first, make sure that the package name was printed correctly

Comment: post your entity class too

Comment: @AndrewToblilko, assume that you mean about the collision between orh.hibernate.* and javax.persistence.*. I used javax.persistence.Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 4.3.6.Final version of hibernate. What hibernate version do you use? With 5.2.1.Final I saw the same problem. Solve by changing hibernate version.

Answer
 https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043461&p=2489997&hilit=hibernate.cfg.xml#p2489997

Answer (score 0):

Your hibernate configuration file(hibernate.cfg.xml) should contain a mapping to entity class.Something like this :

```
<mapping resource="com/igorgorbunov3333/entities/User.hbm.xml"/>
```

Could you please check that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I did the same thing you did (mapped the class directly) and it worked also. It didn't make any sense to me so I looked at the source code and saw this

```
/**
 * Use the mappings and properties specified in the given application resource. The format of the resource is
 * defined in <tt>hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd</tt>.
 *
 * @param resource The resource to use
 *
 * @return this for method chaining
 *
 * @throws HibernateException Generally indicates we cannot find the named resource
 */
public Configuration configure(String resource) throws HibernateException {
    standardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure( resource );
    // todo : still need to have StandardServiceRegistryBuilder handle the "other cfg.xml" elements.
    //      currently it just reads the config properties
    properties.putAll( standardServiceRegistryBuilder.getSettings() );
    return this;
}
```

So basically, not all the items in the hibernate.cfg.xml file are currently being read and I couldn't figure out any alternatives provided by the hibernate API

Comment: Thank u for your reply!